# > Solve in integers $1)\ x^2=y^6+24y^3+192\quad 2)x^3=y^6+24y^3+192$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I encountered this question and have been stuck for couple of days.

> Solve in integers
>
> $$1)\quad    x^2=y^6+24y^3+192$$  $$2)   \quad x^3=y^6+24y^3+192$$
> (Two different diophantine equation.)
> Seems one solution for 1. is $y=-1$ and $x=13$.
> I have tried modular arithmetic and but nothing seems to work so far. I've only been able to reduce it into an equivalent Diophantine Equation i.e.,
> Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are those two separate equations?

Comment: there are two differen t equations

Comment: Hint: $x^2 = (y^3 + 12)^2 + 48$. There are not many situations where two squares differ by $48$ i.e. $x$ and $y^3 + 12$ have to be small enough.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof  Correct, I overlooked that the sixth power is also a square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first: rewrite as

$$x^2 = (y^3 + 12)^2 + 48.$$

The squares differing by 48 are

\begin{align*}
(1,49) \\
(16,64) \\
(121 ,169) \\
\end{align*}

which you can get by solving $(z + 6)^2 = z^2 + 48$,  $(z + 4)^2 = z^2 + 48$ and  $(z + 2)^2 = z^2 + 48$ respectively.

Choosing $x$ to get the right hand squares should pose no trouble. $(y^3 + 12)^2 = 1$ has no integer solution, $(y^3 + 12)^2 = 16$ has $y = -2$ as a solution and $(y^3 + 12)^2 = 121$
has $y = -1$ as a solution.

So the solution set is 
\begin{align*}
(x,y) &= (8, -2) &\lor\\
(x,y) &= (-8, -2) &\lor\\
(x,y) &= (13, -1) &\lor \\
(x,y) &= (-13, -1) 
\end{align*}